# How to delete a file in /download (ora any other folder) in the android external storage with DocumentProvider through Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage

I'm [still] new on android development and about Java and about Kotlin (also an explanation in Java could be ok, however, I'm studying it also, Kotlin is prefered) and I'm struggling for deleting a simple downloaded file into the ExternalStorage.
Of course I enabled permission for read & write, and, even if this code returns a "True", I still can see the untouched file into my Download folder
here the code:
___UPDATE

```
// uri of my file in external storage ~/Download dir
var uri = Uri.parse (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/$myFilename$myExtensionVar")
// file object pointing at uri of file in external storage
val downloadedFile = File(uri.toString())
```

---

```
var deletedBool:Boolean = downloadedFile.delete()
                println("myTag - deleted Boolean: $deletedBool")

                if (deletedBool){
                    println("myTag - uri of file-to-be-deleted: $uri")
                    var secondStepToDelete:Int = context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null)
                    println("myTag - second Step for deletion: $secondStepToDelete")
                }
```

The file i am trying to rid of is a multimedia file (.mp3) and I added the second block of code (the one inside the IF statement) since I found that should work, having to do with the "DocumentProvider" (I'm new and I still don't know how to proper call its methods..) but, of course, It doesn't work at all.
I think I do need the ID (long type i guess) for the file stored into the external storage, however I haven't found yet how to get it

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is `downloadedFile`? Where did you get it? What is `uri`? Where did you get it? "I still can see the untouched file into my Download folder" -- how are you looking for it? (`adb shell ls`? Device File Explorer in Android Studio? an on-device file manager? a desktop file manager? something else?)

Comment: I update my question, thanks

Comment: "I still can see the untouched file into my Download folder" -- how are you looking for it? (`adb shell ls`? Device File Explorer in Android Studio? an on-device file manager? a desktop file manager? something else?)

Comment: I check the persistence of the file in different way: exploring the shared archive through file manager from pc, through ES file manager on device, through explorer in Android Studio.. all of them show the file as i never deleted it. Plus the output of downloadedFile.exists() (after deletion) returns "False"... what's going on?

Comment: `Uri.parse (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/$myFilename$myExtensionVar")` is not a valid `Uri`. A `Uri` has a scheme; yours does not. Use `val downloadedFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download/$myFilename$myExtensionVar")` to try to get the `File` object pointing to that file. There is no `Uri` to be deleted, since you are not getting any of this from `DownloadManager`.

Comment: Ok, I tested it again, it keeps working. Thanks so much, you can post it as answer if you like. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a `File` object, use the `File` constructor. To build a `File` object for a location off of a certain root directory, use the two-parameter `File(File, String)` constructor:

```
val downloadedFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download/$myFilename$myExtensionVar")
```

Unless you are getting a `Uri` from `DownloadManager` or something, there is no `Uri` that you need to `delete()`.

I have more written [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) on external storage and how to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin

```
file.deleteRecursively()
```